# Unnecessary white space between two div elements i nboots

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm coding a website using bootstrap 4 and for some reason that I cant figure out, there is some space between my two wrapper div's in the following code.

```
<!-- News! Ad with "read more" modal popup -->
<div id="news-bar" class="container-fluid bg-white my-0">
 <h2>News</h2>
    <p>Short Description</p>
    <p>more</p>
</div>

<!-- About us / Register for consultation -->
<div id="about-jumbotron" class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-dark text-white margin my-0">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Big Heading</h1>
        <h2>Smaller heading</h2>
        <p>Description text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an imgur [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BoVr.jpg) with a photo of my browser output. Sand brown line is the background-color set for my webpage.

So far I've tried adding my-0 and py-0 to both #about-jumbotron and #news-bar with no success. Also, if i click on the empty space and select inspect element in my web browser it refers to the body tag. As an alternative solution I can set the background color to be the same as one of the div elements but I do want to first try to find a proper solution.

Comment: Please update your CSS elements.

Comment: Make sure that your elements don't have any other effected Css code, use the inspect element and see where does this space come from.

Comment: might your <p> element has bottom margin or padding?

Comment: If you have any padding or margin properties. Please remove those and use width:100%.

Comment: p has a default margin

Comment: I've tried to go through inspect element clicking on each object and none of the boxes (i.e. padding, margin) seem to even go in that  space.

Comment: I have now tried removing all elements except <h1> from both of the containers and the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was that the the h1 and h2 elements had their own margins pushing the bottom  downwards. it was fixed by setting my-0